# Listview header laggy until scrolled

Tags: android

The header for my listview is pretty complex.  It is a ViewPager / FragmentStatePagerAdapter with 5 fragments. The strange thing is that when the view first loads the whole listview is laggy. Once you scroll past the header the listview becomes smooth even when you scroll back up to the header. Any ideas on what may be happening? Thanks for any information

Fragment That contains ListView

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View featuredView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured_series, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, featuredView);        
    View headerView = getHeaderView()
    featuredList.addHeaderView(featuredListHeaderView);
    sAdapter = new SeriesAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<SeriesItem>());
    featuredList.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    return featuredView;
}

 RelativeLayout getHeaderView() {      
        featuredListHeaderView = new FeaturedListHeaderView(getActivity(), this, rHeight, recentHeight);
        featuredListHeaderView.setLayoutParams(params);
        featuredListHeaderView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return featuredListHeaderView;
    }
}
```

The Header contains a Fragment which contains the pager

```
    ...

    pagerAdapter = new FeaturedPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), new ArrayList<SeriesItem>());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    pageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

 private class FeaturedPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<SeriesItem> seriesItems = new ArrayList<SeriesItem>();

    public FeaturedPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<SeriesItem> sItems) {
        super(fm);
        this.seriesItems = sItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        FeaturedPageFragment pf = new FeaturedPageFragment(seriesItems.get(i));
        return pf;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return seriesItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return seriesItems.get(position).getName();
    }

    public void setItems(List<SeriesItem> items) {
        this.seriesItems = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        pageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

FeaturedPageFragment just contains a image with some click listeners

Comment: can you edit your question and add the relevant code?

Comment: @petey I added the relevant code but I think it has something to do with what the listview focuses on?

Comment: I just found the issue. requestLayout is getting called repeatedly until its no longer visible on the screen. Any ideas why?